# Appending array of ObjectIds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an array of ObjectIds in a collection and I want to simply add the ObjectId of another collection.

```
router.post('/add/child', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    switch (req.body.type) {
        case "category":
            Category.findOne({_id: req.body.to})
            .then(category => {
                if (!category) {
                    res.json({error: req.body.type + " not found"});
                }
                category.update({$push: {words: req.body.child}});
                console.log('category', category);
                res.json({category});
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.json(err.response)
            })
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

req.body is:

```
{ type: 'category',
to: '5c312fd6ec0fff1c280aca19',
child: '5c323bed9b0f713aa0d49399' }
```

category is:

```
category { words: [],
    _id: 5c312fd6ec0fff1c280aca19,
    title: 'Weather',
    [__v: 0 }
```

The model for category:

```
category: {
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    variation: {
        type: String
    },
    words: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "words"
    }]
},
```

Comment: just paste your code and select all and click on {} button in editor on top of the answer. It will make your text as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append the array, you need the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)** operator within an update method like [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) or [`findByIdAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). If you are using your existing method, you need to call the [`push`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-push) method on the array itself and then [`save`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save) i.e.:

```
Category.findById(req.body.to).then(category => {
    if (!category) {
        res.json({error: req.body.type + " not found"});
    }
    category.words.push(req.body.child);
    return category.save();
}).then(updatedCategory => {
    console.log('updatedCategory', updatedCategory);
    res.json({ category: updatedCategory });
})
```

A better way which is atomic would be to use the [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) method like:

```
Category.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.to, 
    {'$push': {'words': req.body.child}},
    {new: true},
)
.exec()
.then(category => {
    console.log('category', category);
    if (!category) {
        res.json({error: req.body.type + " not found"});
    }
    res.json({ category });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.json(err.response)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not so clear about what you are looking for. But, I believe you are trying to fetch results from two collections. [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is the best way to do so. You can customize your result using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

```
db.category.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "words",
         localField: "id_of_words",
         foreignField: "id_of_category", // Id of category & words should match.
         as: "docs"
       }
  }
])
```